# What is "off screen" and "on screen" in Xamarin.Forms Animations?

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

In the docs for [TranslateTo](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/xamarin.forms.viewextensions.translateto?view=xamarin-forms) it says:

> To animate a view that receives user touch input from outside of the
>   screen, the developer must first **lay out the view in its final
>   position, then translate the view off screen, and then finally animate
>   the view back to its final position on the screen**. [emphasis mine]

Also in [Simple Animations in Xamarin.Forms](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/animation/simple#translation) (in the Note) it says:

> If an element is initially laid out off screen and then translated
>   onto the screen, after translation the element's input layout remains
>   off screen and the user can't interact with it. Therefore, it's
>   recommended that **a view should be laid out in its final position, and
>   then any required translations performed**. [emphasis mine]

What does that mean in code?

Comment: **off screen**, for example, you have one image, but you put this image off of screen, you can not see this image in ContenPage UI, **On screen**, mean that the image that you put in ContentPage, you can see image in ContentPage. If the image off of screen firstly, then you translate onto the screen, now you can see it, but you may not interact wit it, because the image real location remains off screen,.

Comment: @CherryBu-MSFT Thanks. I posted an answer building on your comment, if I misunderstood you, please let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [a comment above](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60998803/what-is-off-screen-and-on-screen-in-xamarin-forms-animations/61009949#comment107929503_60998803), it seems like the answer is that we need to:

```
child.X = <destination (which is somewhere that the user can see)>
child.TranslateX = <somewhere not seen>
child.TranslateTo(0)
```

(pseudo code as I can't test it at this moment)